# Let git bash launch at current repositories

Tags: windows, git, git-extensions, git-bash

Is there a way to let Git Extension open Git Bash at the current repositories ?
I always need to cd from the home directory. I run Git Extension under Win7.

Comment: in your .bashrc just add cd [whereveryouwant]

Answer (score 6):

You can right-click the Git Bash shortcut, click Properties and change the "Start in" to the path to your repository

Answer (score 2):

With Git version 2.5.2 you can now just CRTL + Right Click and select "Git Bash Here" from the sub menu.

This opens up the bash window in the current repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using msysgit there should be an option to integrate with explorer. You can then right click on a folder and select open git bash here.

Comment: I have a problem with that feature, I right click on the folder select "Git Bash" the bash console opens stays for less that a second and closes itself. Anyone has any idea why would that happen? I'm using windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

The toolbar of GitExtensions has a button that will launch a console MsysGit in the current repository. It is also accessible from the `Git` menu, or Ctrl-G shortcut.

Comment: ..that's my question. I access git via GitExt but the Git Bash will not automatically switch to repository.

Comment: No idea, might be a bug, raise an issue here: https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions/issues